# Give a particular ID to each client in the database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a database witch work with multiple client on the same table. every client can insert and update what he wants, and I have a column IDClient in a way that each client has his own ID, and then he can't touch the data of another client.

The question is how can I choose the ID? How can I know how many client is connected right now, and be sure that I didn't give the same ID to 2 clients?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [`Sequence`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Comment: I have a few questions: 1- Does the client ID need to have alphanumeric pattern or numbers only, 2- The same client always gets the same ID or each time they connect, they get a new ID, 3- How do you recognize the clients? They login to the system?

Comment: 1. It's can be anything. 2. each time they connect they have a new ID, 3. they or connected with password, but they can change the same data

Comment: So how do you know what data belongs to each of your clients?

Comment: I can't know in the beginning, if the client insert something - then he mosts insert also the column clientID, and then I know this row belong to him

Answer (score 0):

Use

> universally unique identifier (UUID)

there is `UUID()` function in MySQL